# CronJob on ubuntu server

Tags: server, cron

Tryin to configure for two running applications on my server, two CronJob.

The command I have to place on ConrJob is:

```
wget -q -O- http://myDOMAIN/cron/index
```

I've done already:

```
crontab -e
```

Edits on the file:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * wget -q -O- http://myDOMAIN/cron/index
*/1 * * * * wget -q -O- http://myDOMAIN2/cron/index
```

But I'm not receiving a successfully mail notification from APP.
In Maildir folder /home/master/ (own mailserver) I just got following message:

```
Return-Path: <master@myDOMAIN>
X-Original-To: master
Delivered-To: master@myDOMAIN
Received: by myDOMAIN (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id 0DA2F1A1F2B; Fri, 16 Jun 2017 16:42:01 +0200 (CEST)
From: root@myDOMAIN (Cron Daemon)
To: master@myDOMAIN
Subject: Cron <master@node01-ubuntu> /myDOMAIN/cron/index
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/master>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=master>
Message-Id: <20170616144201.0DA2F1A1F2B@mmyDOMAIN>
Date: Fri, 16 Jun 2017 16:42:01 +0200 (CEST)

/bin/sh: 1: /myDOMAIN/cron/index: not found
```

Comment: ```/bin/sh: 1: /myDOMAIN/cron/index: not found``` Seems to implicate that your wget commands aren't working correctly. Have you tested them outside of cron?

Comment: @BrianSizemore, how to do that?

Comment: Just open up a shell and run the cron command you are attempting to do. Eg. open shell and run ```wget -q -O- http://myDOMAIN/cron/index``` See if it works successfully or fails with an error. It appears that your cron IS running, just not succeeding since it's printing some errors from bash.

Comment: connecting to server (SSHing form Terminal) executing the `wget` command, nothing happend... no new mail on my Maildir folder, nor happend something if I run che `wget` command form application manually.

Comment: Sorry overlooked something. Remove the ```-q``` flag from the wget command. That is the "quiet" flag which will hide useful output.

Comment: no just executed `crontab -e` insert the `wget`command.. as some disscussions on AksUbuntu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60595/discussion-between-gianni-and-brian-sizemore).

Answer (score 1):

cronjobs need the full path:
try
`/usr/bin/wget -q -O- http://myDOMAIN/cron/index`
or
    /usr/bin/wget -q -O- http://myDOMAIN/cron/index 2> $logfile 
 
and add $logfile to your mail

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script for this (for example, a script like `cron.sh`):

Inside your script, add all the behaviors you want to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -q -O- http://myDOMAIN/cron/index
wget -q -O- http://myDOMAIN2/cron/index
```

then `chmod a+x /path/to/croh.sh`

Finally, add the following to your crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/croh.sh
```